# Progress view with secondary progress for objective C (three colored progress bar)

Tags: ios, objective-c, progress-bar

New progress view in iOS7 changed a lot.
Bunch of people hate it, height cannot be adjusted that trivial, etc.

Problem I came upon is how to show primary and secondary progress, on one progress bar.
For example, If a student answered 8 out 0f 10 questions, and out of those 8, he answered 3 right and 5 wrong, how to show all that?!

[image]

On Android, for example, this is solved quite nicely, you just input data for primary and secondary progress. But in iOS, there is no such option.

How to achieve that in objective C ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

he solution I came up with is fairly simple, and works beautifully for my needs.

I would simply make three labels, with different colors i need, and set their width accordingly. 
Also, by doing this, I was able to set progress bar height to as much I want.

First, you make three Labels.
[image]

You will want to place them one on top of another, to achieve that progress bar look.
I placed the pic below, showing how they actually look.

Gray part of the progress bar will never change it's width (Which we set to be 280for example)
If there is nothing to show, just put _redLabel and _greenLabel width to 0, and you get the progress bar that is not set.

If you want to show the case where there are total of

- 10 questions a student has to answer
- 8 he answered
- 4 answered right (green) 4 answered wrong (red)

  ```
  //question size represents width of one question on progress bar. You just divide the width of the entire bar with number of possible questions (max)
  int questionSize = 280 / num_possible_question;

  int greenProgressSize = green * questionSize;

  CGRect greenProgress = CGRectMake( 20, 95, greenProgressSize, 8 );
  cell.greenLabel.frame = greenProgress;

  int redProgressSize = (red+green) * questionSize;

  CGRect redProgress = CGRectMake( 20, 95, redProgressSize, 8 );
  cell.redLabel.frame = redProgress;

  CGRect grayProgress = CGRectMake( 20, 95, 280, 8 );
  cell.grayLabel.frame = grayProgress;
  ```

And there you go. You have your own progress bar. You can set the width and height as you want, you can set the colors you want and you can even add as much labels as you want.
Also, you can make all those labels programmatically, no need to define them beforehand.